# AWS S3 SDK for PHP: how to get object key from its URL?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since I'm working on legacy code, I would prefer to keep storing objects' URL and not storing their keys. Is there any way to get a key from an URL or must I store keys when I upload files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general public url to object looks like:

```
'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/your-directory/file.txt'
```

where `your-directory/file.txt` - is key to object, hence you can parse key from URL.

But I'd rather keep key in my db because it's easier to work with S3 SDK because you have to provide this key to each method which work with objects in S3.

Comment: how do you parse key from url?